# Is there a SOQL query to get contacts without Case, Account and Chat transcript?

Tags: soql

We're cleaning up our org and want to remove contacts that have nothing associated with it. I want to find contacts without Cases, Accounts and Chat Transcripts. I can find contacts without cases and accounts using command below.

```
select id, name, email, phone, account.name from contact where id not in (select contactid from case) and accountid = null
```

But would like to extend it further by adding in livechattranscript

Thank you

Comment: `...and ID NOT IN (SELECT ContactId FROM LiveChatTranscript)` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to write query like below.

`select id, name, email, phone, account.name from contact where id not in (select contactid from case)   and accountid = null AND id not in (select contactid from LiveChatTranscript)

Comment: Thanks that worked. What is the name of type of query I am writing so I can search for documentation. Where does the 'contactid' name come from as I don't see this on the livechattranscript object?

Thanks

Comment: @HulkBuster, refer the https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_livechattranscript.htm